# Invalid upload ionic resources

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic-v1

When I run command `ionic resources android`, I get this error in my cmd. I have my spashscreen size `1342x2348` and my icon size is `1024x1024`. Both images are in `.png` format still I am getting this error. I have provided the image of my cmd below:

> My System information is:
>
> ```
> Cordova CLI: 8.0.0  
> Ionic Version: 1.3.3  
> Ionic CLI Version: 1.4.0  
> Ionic App Lib Version: 0.0.16  
> OS: Windows 7 SP1  
> Node Version: v6.11.1
> ```

```
(node:6812) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported. If you are
 using the graceful-fs module, please update it to a more recent version.
Ionic icon resources generator
 uploading icon.png...
 ? Invalid upload: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN
"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Notification: Redirect</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color:#333333;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-top: 0px;
  color: #2970A6;
}
a:link {
    color: #2970A6;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
    color: #2970A6;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
p.buttonlink {
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}
.copyright {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #666666;
  margin: 5px 5px 0px 30px;
}
.copyright_alone {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #666666;
  margin: 35px 5px 0px 30px;
}
.details {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #969696;
  border: none;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  margin: 0px 10px 10px 35px;
}

.shadow {
  border: 3px solid #9f9f9f;
  padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;
  margin: 10px 35px 0px 30px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 600px;

  -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #cccccc;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #cccccc;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #cccccc;
  /* For IE 8 */
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=5, Direction=13
5, Color='cccccc')";
  /* For IE 5.5 - 7 */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=5, Direction=135, Co
lor='cccccc');
}
.logo {
  border: none;
  margin: 5px 5px 0px 30px;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>
<div class="logo"></div><p>&nbsp;</p>
<div class="shadow">
<h1>Page Redirection</h1>


<p>
This request is being redirected. If this page does not automatically
redirect, <a href="https://ironport2.iitk.ac.in/B0001D0000N0000N0000F0000S0001R0
004/172.26.141.67/http://res.ionic.io/api/v1/upload">click here to proceed</a>&n
bsp;.
</p>[enter image description here][1]

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/cordova/resources/ says the Splashscreen should be atleast 2732×2732px. Can you maybe provide your project structure?

Comment: im using ionic 1 project structure, and in an earlier project i used 1342x2348px splashscreen i was not getting error, why in this project im getting error

Comment: image size requirements change... mostly due to new devices with odd sizes